# Pseudowire ethernet control word support in scapy

Tags: python, networking, scapy

Is there any support for PW ethernet control word in scapy? I need to create a packet that contains this control word. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Did some research into the scapy manual about how to build new layers and I have written this code. I took some example from the mpls code in scapy. I have tested it and it seems to add the PW Ethernet Control Word in the packet.

```
from scapy.packet import Packet, bind_layers, Padding
from scapy.fields import IntField
from scapy.layers.inet import IP
from scapy.layers.inet6 import IPv6

class PseudowireControlWord(Packet):

    name = "PseudowireControlWord"
    fields_desc = [IntField("SeqNumber", 0)]

    def guess_payload_class(self, payload):
        if len(payload) >= 1:
            ip_version = (ord(payload[0]) >> 4) & 0xF
            if ip_version == 4:
                return IP
            elif ip_version == 6:
                return IPv6
        return Padding
```

Also I added a modification in the mpls.py code in scapy in the `guess_payload_class` function. I think the following code needs to be added:

```
elif ip_version == 0:
    return PseudowireControlWord
```